# SQL Server trigger won't run the complete update statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Problem: I wrote a trigger that is supposed to update the `INVOICE` table after an `INSERT` into the `LINE` table but it won't update the invoice table. The trigger fires but the `Update` statement block won't execute.

I debugged while I executed the `INSERT` into the line table and found out as soon as the it gets to the `UPDATE` statement it jumps over it and doesn't run that code. I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now.

Here is my trigger code

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgInvoiceInsert] ON [dbo].[LINE]
AFTER INSERT
AS
  declare @linUnits numeric(9,2);
  declare @linPrice numeric(9,2);
  declare @invNum   int;

  select @linUnits = LINE_UNITS from inserted;
  select @linPrice = LINE_PRICE from inserted;
  select @invNum = INV_NUMBER from inserted;
BEGIN
 UPDATE i --From here it jumps to the start of the next Update
    SET INV_SUBTOTAL = INV_SUBTOTAL + (@linUnits * @linPrice)
 FROM dbo.INVOICE as i
 WHERE i.INV_NUMBER = @invNum 

 UPDATE i
    SET INV_TOTAL = INV_SUBTOTAL + INV_TAX  
 FROM dbo.INVOICE as i
 WHERE i.INV_NUMBER = @invNum 


 PRINT 'Trigger fired Successfully.'
```

END

Comment: This is the usual behaviour, that jump, because update-set-from-where is one statement and is executed as such. I would hazard a guess that `INV_SUBTOTAL` starts nulled out. Anything you add to null will remain null. Try replacing `INV_SUBTOTAL = INV_SUBTOTAL+ ...` with `INV_SUBTOTAL = isnull(INV_SUBTOTAL, 0) + ...`. If this would not do, add `print @@rowcount` after first `UPDATE` and observe results in `messages` pane. If you see zero then you'll know something is wrong with `@invnum`.

Comment: Oh, and listen to marc_s' advice. This is just to find the reason why your current implementation is not working, but you should try to replace variables with update based on join between `invoice` and derived table `select INV_NUMBER, sum(LINE_UNITS * LINE_PRICE) total from inserted group by INV_NUMBER`.

Comment: thanKsss so much!! The INV_SUBTOTAL with null so i adjusted it and it worked fine. I have come here more often than spending days pulling out my hair. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Well, using a statement like this:

```
select @linUnits = LINE_UNITS from inserted;
```

indicates that you're assuming that the trigger fires **per row** - it does **not**.

SQL Server triggers are fired **once per statement** - so if your statement inserts multiple rows into the `Line` table, your trigger will fire **once** for the complete statement, but the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain **multiple rows** of data.

So you need to rewrite your trigger to take that into account - the `Inserted` table can (and **will!**) contain multiple rows - and your trigger code needs to deal with that.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: just fixed some typos, highlighted the table name in backticks to make it stand out, used `SQL Server` instead of just `SQL` - stuff like that ...

Comment: sounds like you've got a lot of time on your hands :)